# Where are all the Xehanort reports located?

Tags: kingdom-hearts-birth-by-sleep

I just picked up Kingdom Hearts Birth By Sleep and I would like to get all the Xenahort reports on the first runthrough. In which characters' scenarios and at what locations are each of the reports located?

Comment: This game should have its own tag (I'm surprised there aren't more KH questions on the website, honestly).  I dunno abbreviation guidelines though.

Comment: @Shinrai I'm in the process of writing up a meta post regarding just that, actually

Comment: Shinrai [Meta post is here](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/3289/how-should-we-tag-kingdom-hearts-birth-by-sleep) Regarding the lack of questions on the site, BBS came out when we were only 4 months into existence, and all the rest had been out a long time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In chronological order:

### Terra

- **Report #2**: Obtained automatically after beating Radiant Garden's second boss.
- **Report #5**: Reward for completing Mirage Arena's Weaver Fever mode.
- **Report #8**: Given to you after defeating the boss during your return visit to Land of Departure; unmissable
- **Report #11**: Obtained automatically after beating the final boss in Terra's story.

### Ventus

- **Letter**: Obtained automatically after beating the orbs of light enemies in Land of Departure at the beginning of Ventus' story.
- **Report #1**: Inside a treasure chest in the Launch Deck area of the Deep Space world. You will need to use your anti-gravity device to make crates float and then move to the east side of the room.
- **Report #9**: Obtained automatically while on Destiny Island, after a cutscene
- **Report #12**: Inside a treasure chest in the Seat of War area in the Keyblade Graveyard. To your right where you start in this area will be an area surrounded by large cliffs. You will find the chest along the northern wall.
- **Report #10**: Obtained automatically after beating the final boss in Ventus' story.

### Aqua

- **Report #6**: Obtained automatically after beating Enchanted Dominion's boss.
- **Report #3**: Inside a chest in Merlin's house; hard to miss.
- **Report #4**: Obtained automatically after a cutscene in Mysterious Tower.
- **Report #7**: Obtained automatically after beating the final boss in Aqua's story.

[Source.](http://www.examiner.com/video-game-guide-in-national/kingdom-hearts-birth-by-sleep-xehanort-reports-location-guide)

Comment: Great answer, exactly what I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: @FallenAngelEyes You bet, kid! *thumbs up*

Comment: Report #5 is not right. You have to beat the whole arena mode for it

Comment: @user I'm afraid you're incorrect. I am only arena lvl 16 and I have report #5. You do get report #5 from the weaver fever arena.